# Cannot reliably load data from database until Tomcat server is restarted

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I am using Hibernate/JPA in an application to interface with a database. If I add something to the database, and click on the key that starts the function that loads the database items for display, I get unreliable results until I exit the application and restart the Tomcat server. After I do that, then the data I added to the database appears each time I hit SEARCH. I know that this is a vague problem description, but does anybody have any ideas as to what could be causing this. Just exiting the web app and reentering it does not fix the problem. Thanks for any hints you can give.

Comment: okay , what kind of entity mapping you are doing. Show us some query or the way you load the data

Comment: This is the problem. It is a big application that I inherited. Most of the time the EntityManager is obtained by a getEntityManager() method. I will try to find an exact copy of a query.

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me once, and it was due to the fact that I was not committing my transactions. If you are not using a Transaction Manager, and you are manually creating transactions, you can't forget to commit it, otherwise changes won't be shown instantly.

```
try {
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(entity);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am committing all of my transactions. Besides, if the data was improperly placed in the table, why would restarting the server make a difference? Besides, I actually look in the database via MySQL workbench, and the data is in the table as it should be.

Comment: In my case, we were not committing the transactions neither closing the session, so we could actually see the changes in the database, but we couldn't manage to have hibernate fetch them. That is why I proposed to look at the transaction, because we were having the same issue that you are having right now.

Now, why when restarting the application you can see the changes, in our case could of been that the when the application closed, instead of rolling back the transactions, maybe it was committing them for us.